Why are New Year's Eve celebrations called "First Night"?
First Night refers to artistic and cultural celebrations that take place on New Year's Eve in a number of US cities. They're offshoots of a celebration that began in Boston in 1975.
I'm curious how it came to be called First Night. It's the last night of the year, so it would make more sense to call it Last Night.
